# MySQL: eliminating functions from queries

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I write this mysql query **without** using functions?

```
SELECT word  
FROM dvddict 
  JOIN dvdrevdict 
  ON word=RIGHT(revword, 4) 
WHERE LENGTH(revword)=9;
```

The dvddict table has a column `word` and the dvdrevdict table has a column `revword`, which is just the reverse of the `word` column. I want to write it without having to use both `RIGHT()` and `LENGTH()` functions.

Thanks!!

Comment: why do you want to remove the functions? to move to a different platform?

Comment: Perhaps the reasoning is that they are causing difficulty in utilizing indices.

Comment: Of course they are. But RIGHT(revword, 4), even if you rewrite it using LIKE, can't be solved using indexes. If the problem is index using, he must use a more complex solution - but we don't know if this is the reason of the question.

Comment: @Federico That's what I was getting at. More aptly phrased, perhaps the difficulty utilizing indices is the reason.

Comment: In that case (but he doesnt talk anymore...) he should use a TRIGGER to insert the result of word=RIGHT(revword, 4) and LENGTH(revword) into 2 columns. MariaDB has an easier way to do this: virtual (persistent) columns.

Comment: You are correct - thanks for your prompt replies!! I want to use an index on the revword column to optimize the query. I don't know how to insert a TRIGGER into a SELECT statement...

Comment: I'll try adding the two columsn and go from there, unless anybody has a better idea.

Comment: I have added a column for the 9-letter words --LENGTH(revword)=9 -- but can't figure out the second column. Any help?

Comment: GOT iT Done!! Thanks for suggestions, Federico

Comment: Actually, you might consider dropping the revword table.  It's a calculated value which breaks normalization.  For @ChrisBain, functions used as shown in this question tend to run slower than the query would without functions, index or no index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two columns `revword_right` and `revword_length` to `dvdrevdict`, then have a trigger populate them on insert or update.

Unfortunately MySQL has no function based indexes which could probably help you (in the where length.. case) as well if your goal is to speed things up.